# How to change the font of particular text in a paragraph when writing a word document using Python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I am using Python to parse an excel spreadsheet and write documentation to a word document.  I want to highlight binary substrings e.g. '001' by having the numbers appear in dark red.  I can find the substrings using re being any text which is a binary number sequence between single quotes, that is not my question. The question is how do I put the highlighting on just those characters within the paragraph?  The format I would like to end up with is like the following:

[image: final format]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Paandittya's code below shows an example. The key concept is that character formatting (font) is specified at the *run* level. All text in a run shares the same character formatting. So you need to break the binary substrings out into a separate run and set its formatting to your desired look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from docx import Document 
from docx.shared import RGBColor 

document = Document() 
run = document.add_paragraph()
binary_run = run.add_run('your_binary_code')
binary_run.font.color.rgb =  RGBColor(rgb_color_code_goes_here)
cmplt_run = binary_run.add_run('rest of the text goes here')
```

This will change the font color of ur binary code to the color code you provide. Refer [python-docx documemtation](http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html&hl=en-IN#a.font-color) to understand more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Am I correct in thinking that the b_run.font should read binary_run.font?  So the answer is to make the paragraphs in "runs" changing the font of the bit you want to highlight? Note that in my example the first character ( the single quote) is in the normal font so I would add this before the binary_run= statement?

Comment: Sincere apologies for error in the code. The 7th line should indeed have `binary_run` instead of `b_run`. I have edited the code. You pointed that out correctly. And yes you are correct in stating that you can mutually exclusively set formatting of each run and keep joining them using `add_run`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Paandittya for the inspiration, here is my working code:

```
def highlight_binary(par, text):
''' Add text to paragraph while highlighting binary in dark red
    intputs:
    par    => the paragraph to add text to
    text   => the text with 0 or more binary strings in it 
'''
BINARY_STR = re.compile("'[01]+'")

for occurance in re.findall(BINARY_STR, text):
    pos = text.find(occurance)
    par.add_run(text[:pos+1]) # +1 -> opening quote in normal text 
    text = text[pos+len(occurance)-1:] # -1 -> closing quote in normal text
    hl = par.add_run(occurance[1:-1]) # remove quotes from highlighted part
    hl.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(192,0,0)

if text: # any text left?
    par.add_run(text)
```